# How does a black hole slow time?

Tags: general-relativity, time, reference-frames, observers

I've been reading about black holes, and I keep coming across the fact that time runs slower near a them.  My questions are: Does this mean that if you left Earth at age 30 and spent 30 years near the black hole, then you would be 45 years old?  Do you get older more slowly, because if it's all the same what is the point of travelling near a black hole?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How exactly does time slow down near a black hole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25759/)

Answer (score 1):

If you leave earth at age 30 and live for 30 years near a black hole, time will pass more slowly for you and normal for the people on the earth. I don't know the exact age you will be when you spend 30 years near a black hole, but when you return to earth you will be younger than others who had the same age as yours when you left. In other words, others at the same age as yours will be 60 years old and you will be a lot younger.